# What is the specified key size for TripleDES in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, tripledes

So I'm trying to use the TripleDES algorithm in C#.

However, I keep getting an error saying that its not the specified key size.

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Its occurring on the line:

```
tripledes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(112);
```

pdb is an Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

So yeah, how do I fix this error?

Comment: Isn't that 112 bytes not bits that pdb is returning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3DES Key Size Matter in C#.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632211/3des-key-size-matter-in-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

Should be 128 or 192. .NET Framework will only use the 112 or 168 bits, but you should specify 128 or 192.

Answer (score 1):

Legal Key Size depends on your algorithm - see [SymmetricAlgorithm.LegalKeySizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes.aspx).