# How to set theTripleDES Key in .NET / C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, des, tripledes

I'm working with `TripleDES` in C# and according to the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx), `TripleDES` can function with two or three 56-bit keys and uses three iterations of DES.  However, I can't figure out how to specify how many keys to use, and what those keys are.  In fact, all examples I can find of show `TripleDES.CreateEncryptor()` being called with one or no keys.  In addition, the `TripleDES` class only has one `Key` property.

How do I specify the second and third keys for `TripleDES`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key.aspx) property, you'll see: "This algorithm supports key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in increments of 64 bits.".

If you want 2-key TripleDES, set the key to a 16-byte key. If you want 3-key TripleDES, set it to a 24-byte key. See [this post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632211/3des-key-size-matter-in-c-net)

The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options), lists the different keying options.

The reason is there is a [meet-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack), and 2-key TripleDES let's you avoid the attack while only using two keys. Unfortunately, there are other attacks, and so NIST considers it's strength to be about 80-bits of security. 3-key TripleDES is also vulnerable, and only has an effective strength of 112-bits.

If you have a choice, you should prefer AES over TripleDES.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the key length part.  Well that clears that up.  I only need TripleDES for legacy support.  Thanks!